# why are only the last two #html, #media query breakpoint, #links working?

Tags: html, hyperlink, media, breakpoints

Hello my question is simple. I want link to multiple css stylesheets from my html but when i list the stylesheets only the last two links are being shown in my browser. 
All of the links, css work individually. But when i link all 5 from my html only the last two links work.

```
<head>
<title></title>
<meta charset="UTF-8" >
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="(max-width: 319px)" href="css/minimum.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="(max-width: 480px)" href="css/smartphone-max.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="(min-width: 320px)" href="css/smartphone-min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="(max-width: 1024px)" href="css/ipads-max.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="(min-width: 768px)" href="css/ipads-min.css">
</head>
```

Comment: How did you determine that only the last two work? Perhaps they are overwriting the previous ones?

Comment: I didn't override any px widths in any of my CSS ..and i also didn't override any tags. All the links work individually. I tried loading all the links in 1 html. Only the last two links load.

Comment: @Wally check in browser dev tools if all 5 files are downloaded. This maybe cache problem, add same parameters (like ?v=1) to css links to force downloading new ones.

Comment: I just double checked all 5 css stylesheets are in fact being loaded.. i checked the dev tools and i see all 5 stylesheets. i added the appending "?v=1" to my css links & it still doesn't load the first 3 css stylesheets in chrome browser.